# Return a string in a function

Tags: function, flutter, dart, return, flutter-web

I'm working on a project for location management in a warehouse.
This code checks the available space.
But I have a problem with this code.

When i call the function it returns a string, but the return "locatie is bezet" does't work.
Why is that?

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:transportmanagement/locations/AvailableLocations.dart';

final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
var locations = availableLocations;


Future<String> CheckLocation(Location_check) async{
  // This function checks the avalible space in SGF.
  String checkLocation;
  if (Location_check.isEmpty){
    checkLocation= "Vul een locatie in";
    // return "Vul een locatie in";
  }
  else{
    if (availableLocations.containsKey(Location_check)) {
      // Check if the location is in availablelocations.dart

      // Checks if there is already a pallet on this location in Firebase
      await firestoreInstance.collection("Orders").where("locatie", isEqualTo: Location_check).limit(1).get().then((querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
          //print(result.data());
          checkLocation= "Locatie is bezet";
        });
      });
      // return null;

    }
    else{
      checkLocation= "Locatie bestaat niet";
      // return "Locatie bestaat niet";

    }
  }
  return     checkLocation;
}
```

Calling the code:

```
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                    width: 150,
                    child: TextFormField(
                        autofocus: true,
                        obscureText: false,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          fillColor: Colors.white, filled: true,
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(0)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      onSaved: (String value) {
                        _locatie = value;
                      },
                      validator: (value) {
                          var test = CheckLocation(value);
                          return test;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

Comment: What is the CheckLocation method return?

Comment: It returns a string with the dutch text "there is already a pallet on this location".

Comment: Al the other returns work, but this one not. It think it is because this return is inside a if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Define a string variable inside the function and then return the variable

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:transportmanagement/locations/AvailableLocations.dart';

final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
var locations = availableLocations;


String CheckLocation(Location_check) {
  // This function checks the avalible space in SGF.
  String checkLocation;
  if (Location_check.isEmpty){
    checkLocation= "Vul een locatie in";
    // return "Vul een locatie in";
  }
  else{
    if (availableLocations.containsKey(Location_check)) {
      // Check if the location is in availablelocations.dart

      // Checks if there is already a pallet on this location in Firebase
      firestoreInstance.collection("Orders").where("locatie", isEqualTo: Location_check).limit(1).get().then((querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
          //print(result.data());
          checkLocation= "Locatie is bezet";
        });
      });
      // return null;

    }
    else{
      checkLocation= "Locatie bestaat niet";
            // return "Locatie bestaat niet";

    }
  }
  return     checkLocation;
}
```

I hope this is helpful

**UPDATE**
the  `querySnapshot.docs.forEach` excite after return `checkLocation` variable

so that return null
you must add `await` to  `firestoreInstance.collection("Orders").where("locatie", isEqualTo: Location_check).limit(1).get()`

see that

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:transportmanagement/locations/AvailableLocations.dart';

final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
var locations = availableLocations;


String CheckLocation(Location_check) {
  // This function checks the avalible space in SGF.
  String checkLocation;
  if (Location_check.isEmpty){
    checkLocation= "Vul een locatie in";
    // return "Vul een locatie in";
  }
  else{
    if (availableLocations.containsKey(Location_check)) {
      // Check if the location is in availablelocations.dart

      // Checks if there is already a pallet on this location in Firebase
    await  firestoreInstance.collection("Orders").where("locatie", isEqualTo: Location_check).limit(1).get().then((querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
          //print(result.data());
          checkLocation= "Locatie is bezet";
        });
      });
      // return null;

    }
    else{
      checkLocation= "Locatie bestaat niet";
            // return "Locatie bestaat niet";

    }
  }
  return     checkLocation;
}
```

Comment: Thans for your help! Your code Is looking good. But also when I call this code it returns all the checkLocations, but the "Locatie is bezet" returns a null.

Comment: This means that the condition is not met or that there is no document in the snapshot

Comment: try to print result of document

Comment: add await before `firestoreInstance.collection("Orders").where("locatie", isEqualTo: Location_check).limit(1).get()`

Comment: I added the "print(checkLocation)"  before "return checkLocation" and the result is null. But when i add the "print("test") below the "checkLocation= "Locatie is bezet" the result is test. So the code triggers the print statement.

Comment: Nice that is the trick! But there is still one problem. When i want to use await in need to add Future<String> before the function and when I want to execute this code ik telling me this error. '"error: The return type 'Future<String>' isn't a 'String', as required by the closure's context. (return_of_invalid_type_from_closure at [transportmanagement] lib/inboeken/inboeken_aanmaken.dart:245)"'

Comment: when you call function add await before it

Comment: `String location = await CheckLocation(Location_check);` or `CheckLocation(Location_check).then((value){location=value}) ;`

Comment: for more information about Future read  this [link](https://medium.com/@jelenaaa.lecic/when-to-use-async-await-then-and-future-in-dart-5e00e64ab9b1)